# How to close the session sharing under tomcat7?

Tags: session, tomcat, session-cookies, tomcat7

I have two host in tomcat:

```
<Host name="host1.domain.com" .../>
<Host name="host2.domain.com" .../>
```

I found that when i login host1,which will save a "USER_ID" in session,host2 could also get a "USER_ID" in session.

Does it mean tomcat7 will sharing session under a  ?

Then how to disable it, i don't want them share the session.

Comment: Please be more specific: any webapp can save any data in any session. What is the significance of the string "USER_ID"?

Comment: I mean, i save something in session named "USER_ID" in host1. But host2 can get it in host2's session.

Comment: Something must not be as you are describing it: either you have the same data in USER_ID in two separate sessions and you are reading your trace information incorrectly, or your host(s) and webapp(s) are not configured as you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each webapp has its own set of sessions that do not overlap with any other webapp. Even if the same webapp has been deployed twice (once under host1 and once under host2), they are considered distinct and the sessions will not be shared.